# View update issue when coming back on same page Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am displaying list using `*ngFor`. It is working fine at once but when I come back on same page after going on any page, it is not updating view. It is calling api and I can see data in console.
Please help me to solve this. Check my below code. I am calling it on `ngOnit`.
**Code :**

```
this.Service.getList(this.model)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                    this.listData.push(data[i]);
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: What is our component changeDetection strategy ? is it OnPush ?

Comment: @xe4me, means ? I am not updating any data here. I am going on another page and coming back on this page.

Comment: can you show us your component ? does your component have changeDetection property defiend ?

Comment: @xe4me, no. I have not defined any changeDetection.

Comment: Alright , try calling this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

Comment: @xe4me, exactly where ?

Comment: After your for loop 
you need to inject changeDeterorRef:ChangeDetectorRef into your constructor as well

Comment: @xe4me, it worked. :) Thank you so much. Is it necessary to use in all pages where I am showing list ???

Comment: Absolutely not , it shouldn't be like that at all , when you do this and it works , it means that subscription does not update the view for many reasons and you'd need to find that

Comment: This is of course not gonna cause any problems , you're just simply invoking angular's changeDetection manually , but the question is why didn't it invoke itself !?

Comment: @xe4me, It is working fine for first time, only issue is when i come back again on same page.  What should I check for this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130096/discussion-between-jeeten-parmar-and-xe4me).

Comment: @xe4me, I found the issue.